# Why does ethanol have a health rating of [2] in NFPA 704 whereas methanol, which is far more toxic, has a rating of only [1]?

Tags: safety, toxicity

Why Ethanol has the blue health hazard rating of 2 in NFPA 704 where as both Acetone and Methanol which are far more toxic than Ethanol have a rating of only 1?    (Click on each link to see the NFPA diamond)

- [Ethanol](https://cameochemicals.noaa.gov/chemical/667)
- [Methanol](https://cameochemicals.noaa.gov/chemical/3874)
- [Acetone](https://cameochemicals.noaa.gov/chemical/8)

Comment: it's the "fire diamond", F in NFPA states for fire hazard. Anyway, the health info (blue) difference is strange.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the rating is dependent on toxicity tests.

The acute oral toxicity [LD50](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_lethal_dose) value of acetone is [5800 mg/kg](http://www.sciencelab.com/msds.php?msdsId=9927062)

The acute oral toxicity [LD50](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_lethal_dose) value of methanol is [5628 mg/kg](http://www.sciencelab.com/msds.php?msdsId=9927227)

The acute oral toxicity [LD50](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_lethal_dose) value of ethanol is [3450 mg/kg](https://www.sciencelab.com/msds.php?msdsId=9923955)

Low LD50 values means that only a small amount of chemical is needed to kill someone. According to these values, you would need to ingest a larger amount of acetone or methanol to die.I am not sure how valid these toxicology test are. Fun fact: fructose is deadlier than methanol according to LD50 values.

Furthermore, there appears to be some variation in the values as well. Wikipedia lists the LD50 value of ethanol as [7,060 mg/kg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_lethal_dose#cite_note-21). 
Maybe this question can be addressed at Biology SE.

Comment: LD 50 is a rotten metric for the relative toxicity of methanol and ethanol. This might be because methanol kills you slowly and its *acute* toxicity isn't the one that matters.